# How to concatenate a Twig variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have a `Twig` template that contains a `Javascript` code. In my control I pass an array into the template. I'm using `Javascript` to display a map using Google Maps Api for `Javascript`. I created a variable that I incremented at each loop round when creating the markers. This variable I want to use this variable to access each element of the table according to the given index. Since the array is in twig, the index is in Javascript.  concatenation seems complicated.

Here's exactly the line concerned by this question :

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>{{ services['+j+']["name"] }}</strong><br>');
```

And here' the full example:

```
var j = 0;
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location
    });

    service.getDetails(
    {
        placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
    },
    function(place, status) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>{{ services['+j+']["name"] }}</strong><br>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    });

    j++;

    return marker;    
});
```

Comment: I think what you actually meant is "<div><strong>" + services[j]["name"] + "</strong><div>"

Comment: Yes but it does not work.

Comment: Move j++ inside the inner function, under infowindow.open

Comment: You are setting var j = 0; but after that i cant find anything that changes j in the function...

Comment: @SPlatten it is not the matter i guess (i did it). look before the return statment

Comment: Just to make sure: `services` is a twig array and **not** a javascript array?

Comment: @TobiasXy exactly !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser (where the javascript is executed) won't even know Twig was involved, because at that point the whole Twig code is already rendered into plain HTML/CSS/Javascript. Therefore it isn't possible to use Javascript to manipulate the Twig rendering.

Instead you could

**1. Pass the whole services array to Javascript**

That would look like this (array is passed in line 2 and the line of `infowindow.setContent` is using the javascript array now):

```
var j = 0;
var services = {{ services|json_encode|raw }};
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location
    });

    service.getDetails(
        {
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
        },
        function(place, status) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + services[j]["name"] + '</strong><br>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        });
    j++;
    return marker;

});
```

Problem here is, you would literally pass the whole services array to the client. If it is huge or contains sensible information, you should not do that. Instead you should look at solution 2:

**2. Pass an adapted service_names array to Javascript**

Where you render the Twig template also pass a `service_names` array:

```
$twig->render('the_template.twig', [
    'services' => $services,
    'service_names' => array_column($services, 'name')
]);
```

Then adapt the solution from answer 1 accordingly:

```
var j = 0;
var service_names = {{ service_names|json_encode|raw }};
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location
    });

    service.getDetails(
        {
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
        },
        function(place, status) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + service_names[j] + '</strong><br>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        });
    j++;
    return marker;

});
```

Comment: `var service_names = {{ service_names|json_encode|raw }};` This was a part of the solution, I know to proceed after that. Thanks